# De Certeau’s shtick is to read the environment as one would a script: that is, like written speech

Tags: grammar, vocabulary

De Certeau’s shtick is to read the environment as one would a script: that is, like written speech.

Is another “read" missing after "would" or is it correct? If it is correct, how can"would"indicates"read" here?

Answer (score 1):

The sentence is correct, the author has used [ellipsis](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/about-words-clauses-and-sentences/ellipsis), and the meaning "as one would ***read*** a script" is implied.

> Ellipsis happens when we leave out (in other words, when we don’t use) items which we would normally expect to use in a sentence if we followed the grammatical rules.

In this case, the device used is [gapping ellipsis](http://www.glottopedia.org/index.php/Gapping)

> Gapping is a kind of ellipsis construction in which repeated verbs in coordinate structures are omitted. The term was introduced by Ross (1967) as a kind of conjunction reduction rule.

Example

> See the following example from English where the application of gapping on (1a) results in (1b).
>
> (1) Gapping (borrowed from Ross 1967):
>
> (a) The boy works in a skyscraper and the girl works in a quonset hut.
>
> (b) The boy works in a skyscraper and the girl in a quonset hut.

In case you are wondering, a quonset hut is a building similar to the picture below:

[image: Quonset hut]

Comment: In the UK, I think we call that a Nissan hut, but I might be wrong, technically.

Comment: I think they're cousins :) according to https://web.mst.edu/~rogersda/umrcourses/ge342/quonset_huts-revised.pdf Nissen huts (named after  Lt Colonel Peter Nissen, a
Canadian officer in the Royal Engineers during the
First World War) are smaller than quonsets. I had no idea!

Comment: Erm, yes. 'Nissan' is the car company. Thanks for the correction.

Comment: If we are being exact, a Quonset hut (capital Q) is named after Quonset Point, Rhode Island, where the first American huts, based on the British design, were made.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey. Thanks for the correction. I had no idea of that either.